# Wordpress SSL - Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl

I made a url change from my Wordpress site to use "https: //", When adding the change both in Settings> General Options as well as in the .htaccess file, I return internal error on the server.

The apache log has the following information:

> [Wed Oct 03 07:29:10 2018] [error] [client 177.73.98.2] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., Referer: https://meusite.com.br/

My .htaccess I put the following rule to force SSL

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^ index \ .php $ - [L]
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}! -F
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}! -D
RewriteRule. /index.php [L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond% {SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^ (. *) $ https://meusite.com.br/$1 [R, L]
</ IfModule>`
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't make changes to your `.htaccess` file.
The reason you ran into this issue is because the `WordPress Address (URL)` and `Site Address (URL)` setting inside WordPress Admin is still pointing to `http` version of your URL.

What happens is, when a visitor visits your website, `.htaccess` rule redirects his request to `https` version and then loads WordPress, which recognizes that the settings point to `http` version and thus triggers a redirect to `http` version. This redirect, once again, gets caught by the `.htaccess` rule and goes on and on until timeout.

***What you need to DO:***
1. Remove any modification to `.htaccess` file.
2. Update `WordPress Address (URL)` and `Site Address (URL)` in your Wordpress Admin to point them to the `https` version of URL.
3. Install [WordPress HTTPS (SSL) Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/)

Comment: My error_log return to message:
 `[Thu Oct 04 06:50:38 2018] [alert] [client 69.162.124.233] /home/storage/6/ea/ea/meusite/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: http://meusite.com.br/`
 `[Thu Oct 04 06:50:52 2018] [alert] [client 193.236.44.120] /home/storage/6/ea/ea/meusite/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: https://www.google.com/`
I thinking that it can be <Directory>
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
</Directory>

Comment: My answer says `don't modify .htaccess`. I can't help you with .htacces rules

Comment: In the link it gives a suggestion to change the .htaccess, but it really is not that.

Comment: I did not add anything in the .htaccess I just changed the url to https, I already disabled plugins and the theme and my apache log continues:
`Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`  
@Jaswinder Singh Would you help me?

Comment: Have you installed the plugin i suggested?

Comment: Also when i said don't modify .`htaccess` i was talking about `RewriteRule ^ (. *) $ https://meusite.com.br/$1 [R, L]` -> this is a custom rule.

Comment: Replace your .htaccess file with this [WordPress Default .htaccess, (use basic wp)](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess#Basic_WP)

Comment: I left the basic configuration of htaccess for wordpress, but it still generates this redirect error.

The request has exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to the probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the threshold, if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., Referer:

Comment: please paste your `.htaccess` file on pastebin.com and provide me a link. or update it in your answer

Comment: File htaccess BASE Wordpress - [htaccess wp](https://pastebin.com/Hqza7StG)

Comment: Things i need to know before a proper diagnosis: is this error only for wordpress files, can you access other files directly? are you on a VPS? does this error happen on a specific URL only? are you using the SSL plugin i suggested? does this error happen only when you visit `http` version and not when directly typing `https`?

Comment: Try replacing the default `.htaccess` file with this one [pastebin.com/0JRvcmFQ](https://pastebin.com/0JRvcmFQ), let me know what the result is!

Comment: Hi, thanks for help!
But I could not solve
----
Things I need to know before proper diagnosis: is this error only for wordpress files, can you access other files directly?
I can not access other files on the server when I activate https

are you on a VPS?
Not

does this error happen on a specific URL only?
All URLs with digitador.com.br

are you using the SSL plugin i suggested?
I used

does this error happen only when you visit http and not when typing directly https?
Only when access via https, the certificate is installed badly when configuring in wordpress generates error.

Comment: Did you try replacing  your .htaccess file with this one [pastebin.com/0JRvcmFQ](https://pastebin.com/0JRvcmFQ)